# Flip animation not working in Safari

Tags: html, css

I have made an animated profile picture and when hovered on it flips around and shows the backside. It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari.

It does flip around, but the image changes back to the frontside but facing in opposite direction.

this is what I see 1 second after I hover on it. (This is the front-side, but flipped horizontally)

[image]

Link: http://www.ik-ben-zzp.nl/testsite/index.php

Here is the HTML CSS of the profile picture.

What is the problem here?

Thanks

Ps. Tested on Safari iPad

```css
.roundedImage {
 overflow:hidden;
 width: 200px;
 height:200px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
    -webkit-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -moz-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -ms-animation:pop-in 0.8s;

}

.flip-container {
 perspective: 1000;
 z-index:3;
 margin-bottom:200px;
}
 
 .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 
}


.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  -ms-transition: 0.6s;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
}


.front, .back {
 backface-visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}


.front {
 transform: rotateY(0deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


.back {
 transform: rotateY(180deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
 }
 
.front div, .back div {
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -moz-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
    -ms-animation:pop-in 0.8s;
 border: 4px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover')">

<div class="roundedImage">

<div class="flipper">

<div class="front">
<div style="background: url(Images/ProfileFront.jpg); height:200px; background-size: cover;"></div>
</div>

<div class="back">
<div style="background:url(Images/ProfileBack.jpg); height:200px; background-size:cover;"></div>
</div>

</div> <!--FLIPPER-->
</div> <!-- ROUNDED IMAGE -->
</div>  <!-- FLIP CONTAINER -->
```

Comment: did you read the comments of that article : http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Answer (score 1):

Add -webkit- prefixes to all necessary css property. You missed to  'backface-visibility'.

Comment: I had the same issue and the only property that I needed `-webkit` on was `backface-visibility` and this fixed everything.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');" in all your div's in html and add below javascript. you can comment 'return false' incase you have any serverside clickable items inside the divs of 'front' or 'back to work

```
$('.flip-container').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.flipper').addClass('hover').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
    return false;
});
```